# Column in a pandas dataframe getting incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas

Very likely I made an elementary mistake in the following construction, but I cannot find which.

I have a list of csv-files that I combine into a dataframe in the following way:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in filelist])
```

Now I want to change the elements of the column `XXX`. Since it cannot be done with a mapping, I proceed in the following way:

```
xxx = list(df['XXX'])
print(xxx[535:550])
(* ['30', '30', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6'] *)
```

From this list, I construct a list `yyy`, with the following result:

```
print(yyy[535:550])
(*['030-11', '030-12', '004-01', '004-02', '004-03', '005-01', '005-02', '005-03', '005-04', '005-05', '005-06', '005-07', '005-08', '006-01', '006-02'] *)
```

This is as it has to be. I store this result in the column:

```
df['XXX'] = pd.Series(yyy)
```

I read back the result:

```
xxx = list(df['XXX'])
print(xxx[535:550])

(* ['030-11', '030-12', '001-01', '001-02', '001-03', '001-04', '001-05', '001-06', '001-07', '001-08', '002-01', '002-02', '002-03', '002-04', '002-05'] *)
```

That are not the values that I expected. It starts going wrong at position 537. That is the first line of the second csv-file, so probably my error is in the construction of the dataframe. Any hint is highly appreciated.

**Edit**

The list `yyy` is constructed from the list `xxx` in the following way (it counts successive equal elements of the list `xxx`):

```
sc = ['', 0]
yyy = []
for x in xxx:
    if sc[0] == x:
        sc[1] += 1
    else:
        sc = [x, 1]
    yyy.append(f"{sc[0].zfill(3)}-{str(sc[1]).zfill(2)}")
```

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to create a new column in a different format based on the original column.  Have you tried using .apply() ?

Comment: @Gigi All lists are lists of strings. I am a beginner in pandas, so how should I have used apply()?

Comment: Could you add to your post what function you applied to the strings?  df.apply(your_func)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the complete solution but I think it is a good first step to what you are trying to achieve.

```
df['yyy'] = df.groupby(['xxx']).cumcount() + 1
```

You could also add the zfill() part.

```
df['yyy'] = df['xxx'].apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(3)) + '-' (df.groupby(['xxx']).cumcount() + 1).apply(lambda x: str(x).zfill(2))
```

You could add filter somewhere in there to apply the transformations only where xxx contains a number.

**EDIT**

To answer your actual question, I am guessing that it might have to do with the indexes that repeat from the concatenation. 1st csv : [1, 2, 3, 4] 2nd csv : [1, 2, 3, 4]. Concat : [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4].

Your Series created from yyy, has indexes [1, 2, 3, 4, **5, 6, 7, 8**]

When you append the transformed yyy, it merges based on the wrong indexes.

Try running your first import with the ingore_index parameter set to True.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in filelist], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your highly illustrative demonstration how I could have used apply. I am very happy with it. As @Gigi surmised, this construction works as well in my concatenated dataframe. But I still would like to understand why my construction failed to work with the concatenated dataframe, while it does work with a direct dataframe. Did I do something that is not allowed, or is this sort of buggish behavior? Again, I highly appreciate your comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I think might be the issue. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Perfect! With that setting there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas dataframes, it is generally better to use builtin functionality if possible rather than to transform to a list.

This might be useful to you:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Pandas .apply method applies a function to your series or dataframe.

You should be able to apply whatever you are doing in your function that changed your lists using the pandas apply method.  It's like mapping but it performs a function on an entire series.

Sudo-code (not tested) - provide the function or an approximate if you need more details

```
series_to_change = df["Your column"]
multiply_all_by_10 = series_to_change.apply(lambda x: x*10)
```

This would multiply every item by 10

You can also use named functions, numpy functions, etc - see the pandas documentation for details

Comment: Thanks for your interest and help. I did not see a way to use apply for my construction; I added it to my question. My feeling is (please correct me if I am wrong) that apply can only be used with functions of one argument, the entry in the list, and my function needs  subsequences of the list of a prori unknown length.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use it with more arguments than just one - but I'm not 100% sure.  I have to head out for bit but will stop by this post later if someone else hasn't answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'col1': ['30', '30', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '6', '6']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.col1.apply(lambda x: x.zfill(3)) + '-' + df.groupby(['col2']).cumcount().pad(limit=2).astype(str)
```

and the result is:

```
0     030-0
1     030-1
2     004-0
3     004-1
4     004-2
5     005-0
6     005-1
7     005-2
8     005-3
9     005-4
10    005-5
11    005-6
12    005-7
13    006-0
14    006-1
```

Comment: Many thanks! But your pad-construction does not give what I want to obtain.